# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, netlify, vite

Config:

**vite v2.6.4**,

**react v17.0.0**,

**firebase v9.5.0**

When I deployed my app on **netlify**, it all went good. But when I go to my app its all blank and the console log me:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

For the sake of my **firebase** project I put the api key in a */.env* file that is ignore by git. I've read the https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html page but don't understand so much what to do.

**.env** file

```
VITE_APP_API_KEY= *thekey*
VITE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN= *theauthdomain*
VITE_APP_PROJECT_ID= *theprojectid
VITE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET= *thebucket*
VITE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID= *themsId*
VITE_APP_APP_ID= *theappid*
```

**.gitignore** file

```
node_modules
.DS_Store
dist
dist-ssr
*.local
.env
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local
```

**Firebase.js** file

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_APP_ID
}
```

*Folder Architechture*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because your initial value for `apikey` needs a string - not an empty.

```
// firebase.js/firebaseConfig
apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY || 'mock_key'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.
I was using named exports, but I solved it by changing to default exports.

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = firebase.auth();

export default auth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set initialValue for apiKey as some string (not empty) as this

`apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY || 'mock_key'`